# Is it possible to stream documents from elastic search?

Tags: streaming, elasticsearch

Is it possible to have a persistant HTTP connection to an elasticsearch where it simply outputs new documents when they are indexed?

For example, I'm adding a theoretical argument called `stream`:

```
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200/documents/_search?stream'

{"_index":"documents", "_type":"doc", "field": "value #1"}
{"_index":"documents", "_type":"doc", "field": "value #2"}
{"_index":"documents", "_type":"doc", "field": "value #3"}
```

... which would keep the connection running, presumably with HTTP chunked mode, until the client disconnects.

The alternative that I'm considering is to execute a GET request every second to the cluster with a time range of a second. I was hoping of a streaming mode to prevent the overhead.

There are elasticsearch [Rivers](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/river/), which seems to be the opposite to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not exist in Elasticsearch [yet](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/1242).

However, you can have a look at this [plugin](https://github.com/derryx/elasticsearch-changes-plugin).

Answer (score 3):

There is a websocket transport (https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-transport-websocket) that will give you streaming.